# How to concentrate geometry in important areas for remesh?

Tags: modeling

I have a high poly human model which I have converted to a low poly human through a remesh. The face of the human is struggling to display well even with solid, high quality bakes from the high poly model.

I was wondering if it would be possible to remesh, but concentrate geometry around places where it really matters (like the face and the hands), whilst keeping the geometry around the torso, arms and legs more sparse?

Any addons which accomplish this as well I'd be interested in learning about

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adaptivity in voxel remesh do this:

[image]